# using more than one button in same view in django

Tags: django, post, button, view, request

I am trying to make a "next" and "back" buttons for displaying 5 elements of my database, every time you click on "next" button, it will display the next 5 elements and if you click "back" button, it will show the 5 previous elements.

The error that shows up when I click on the "next" button is:

Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/notificacions/
Django Version: 3.0.3
Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError
Exception Value:
'back'

my python code in views is:

```
if request.method == 'POST':    

    if request.POST['next']:
        for element in range(5):
            show_notifications.append(notifications_list[the_counter])
            the_counter+=1



    elif request.POST['back']:
        the_counter-=10
        for element in range(5):
            show_notifications.append(notifications_list[the_counter])
            the_counter+=1
```

and my html code is:

{% csrf_token %}
         BackNext

Comment: <tr>
                <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
                <td style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;"><div style="margin-right: 25px;"><button type='submit' method="post" name="back">Back</button><button type='submit' method="post" name="next">Next</button></div></td>
                </form>

Comment: Try this for both buttons. Replace `request.POST['back']` with `request.POST.get('back',default=None)`.It gets the value of the parameter in a POST request or gets None if the parameter is not present. This will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked.